# Are there digital copies of the Restatements of Torts or the Concise Restatement of Torts you can purchase or read online?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, tort

I hope to find something searchable to efficiently work with, and so far I could only find paperback copies.

Comment: This is IMO on-topic: the [official list](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of things on-topic includes "Statutes or court decisions" and "Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory" and either of those should cover this

Comment: @David Siegel Thank you for clarifying and fixing up the question!

Comment: There are not complete sets available for free. It is copyrighted and the owners of the copyright do not license it for free (a practice I find very problematic personally).

Comment: @ohwilleke I used to help the "DIY Bookscanner Project" and improved their design. :) (Greatly in support of knowledge to be shared.)

Comment: @ohwilleke you might also like the answer of shoover. I'm very satisfied. The pages look incredible. The color is authentic, but its so good, I'm almost fooled its actually not a scan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Internet Archive has a copy of [*A Concise Restatement of Torts*](https://archive.org/details/conciserestateme0000abra/page/n1/mode/2up) (2000) in their lending library that is available to be checked out for 1 hour or 14 days. You will need to log in with an [Internet Archive account](https://archive.org/account/login.createaccount.php), but those are free to obtain.

Comment: Note that in general it's not clear that a given book provided by the internet archive is shared legally or their service breaks copyright laws. Best to inform yourself and check if you're worried about breaking copyright laws.

Comment: @ user2705196  There is an argument that the **IA** is infringing copyright in such a case. But the **user** is not, and is doing nothing unlawful even if an infringement case against the IA is won, as long as the user does not redistribute the work.

Answer (score 5):

There are no free legal copies online. They are accessible online through LexisAdvance, HeinOnline and Westlaw: this provides access, but not a downloadable copy.

Answer (score 3):

The Restatements are available on Westlaw and Lexis. I don't know of anywhere they can be viewed for free, other than maybe through pirating/torrent sites.

Answer (score 2):

A Google search finds a number of places where short excerpts are available online, such as https://cyber.harvard.edu/privacy/Privacy_R2d_Torts_Sections.htm which contains section 652.  Various services provide electronic access for an annual fee, several of which want credentials as a retired lawyer or a law student for discounted rates.

Amazon offers the *A Concise Restatement of Torts 2nd Second edition* for $26 used in paperback. It does not seem to offer an electronic version at all.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found, too. Even the excerpts are helpful, thank you! I may as well purchase one from within a jurisdiction where backup copies for personal use are legal, and get my own version from a paperback.